# Dual boot causing my dvd drive to not be recognized?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dvd

I've got dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 16.04 running on a Dell Optiplex. On both operating systems there is no indication of a dvd drive being installed at all. The drive will spin when a disk is inserted but nothing will ever pop up.

```
ls /dev
```

doesn't show anything relating to dvd or cdrom or dvdrw.

Windows device manager also doesn't have a category for the dvd drive.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to diagnose the issue, and if the cause of it could be the partitioned hard drive. I can't seem to get any information about the dvd drive in either windows or ubuntu.

Would an exterior disk drive perform better in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: If Windows can't see the device, then it sounds like the issue is hardware related, not because of an Ubuntu bootup.  Do you see a `/dev/sr0` at all?

Comment: Run command `lshw -short`. Under  **/dev/cdrom** is there a description shown there of your dvd device/?

Comment: unfortunatly `/dev/sr0` doesn't exist, and when I run `lshw -short` there is nothing there about a cdrom. I suppose it probably is hardware issue like you say.

Comment: In which case you need to go into BIOS - tap F2 (2-3/sec) on powering up until BIOS screen appears. Look for Boot tab at the top and navigate there. In your boot order is your dvd drive shown? If you can't get into BIOS, try tapping Delete key instead.

Comment: yes the DVD drive is shown in the BIOS. What does that mean?